# Htaccess Redirect RewriteRule 301 with query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a lot of links like this that I want to do 301

```
RewriteRule ^best-sales?n=10&p=10$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/best-sales [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^3_dickies?n=24&id_manufacturer=3$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/3_dickies [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^imgcmsWilcox%20Culinary%20Arts%20Department.pdf$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com [L,R=301]
```

These links

```
RewriteRule ^157-port-authority-silk-touch-interlock-sport-shirt.html$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/hospitality-housekeeping-polo-shirts/137--port-authority-silk-touch-sport-shirt-with-pocket.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^145-port-authority-extended-size-silk-touch-sport-shirt.html$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/ladies-workwear/151-port-authority-ladies-silk-touch-interlock-sport-shirt.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^217-hanes-stedman-52-ounce-jersey-knit-sport-shirt.html$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/apparel/2329-hanes-comfortblend-ecosmart-jersey-knit-sport-shirt-with-pocket-.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^134-port-authority-long-sleeve-silk-touch-sport-shirt-with-pocket-.html$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/ladies-workwear/132-port-authority-ladies-long-sleeve-silk-touch-sport-shirt-L500LS.html [L,R=301]
```

Without query strings redirects perfectly with same rule but the ones that have a query string or %20% are crating issues.

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)),
"Any help would be appreciated" and "Thanks!" have no place in a good question. It is not impolite to leave that out, but it is wasting readers time when you put it in.

Comment: Well Anthon sorry if i hurted you but i just trying to show little decency to someone who tries to help is that really hurt you ?

Comment: Yes it hurts. I and other visitors to this site would have to wade through hundreds of those "Thanks" a day, if everyone ignored the rules of this site. If you don't agree, please post on [metase] to get the help tour text changed. I saw your post becuase it came up in the Help and Improve queue of questions, that was for a reason.

Comment: Thanks anthon for pointing that out if its stack policy ofcourse i will follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match the query string in a rewrite rule, you need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` and a rewrite cond.

So:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=10&p=10$
RewriteRule ^best-sales$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/best-sales? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=24&id_manufacturer=3$
RewriteRule ^3_dickies$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/3_dickies? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: so i will need to do this for each link that contains query string or %20% in it ?

Comment: FYI how can i do redirect for this link  RewriteRule ^imgcmsWilcox%20Culinary%20Arts%20Department.pdf$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com [L,R=301]

Comment: @PradeepSrivastava Only query strings, the `%20` is a space. So in your regex, you just need `\ ` to match it: `RewriteRule ^imgcmsWilcox\ Culinary\ Arts\ Department.pdf$ http://www.bestbuyuniforms.com [L,R=301]`